# _open returns EINVAL for a shared file

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to open a shared file using _open() function. It returns -1 and errno is 22(EINVAL). I am able to open the shared file in the file explorer. The program and the shared file are in Windows machine.

```
#include<stddef.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
   int fh1;
   char fname[50] = "\\\\192.168.1.115\\data\\RELEASE-PC.err";

   fh1 = _open( fname, _O_RDONLY|_O_BINARY, 384 );
   if( fh1 == -1 )
      printf( "Open failed on input file - %d",errno ); //EINVAL
   else
   {
      printf( "Open succeeded on input file\n" );
      _close( fh1 );
   }
}
```

Any idea why it is failing? Is it permission issue?

Comment: where are you expecting to find the `_open()` function?  I.E. which header file?

Comment: to reference the global variable `errno`, need to include the `errno.h` header file.

Comment: it looks like your trying to open a binary file for input that resides on another computer.   I suspect this is not the correct approach to that activity.   BTW: when I compiled the posted code, on ubuntu linux 14.04, using `gcc`, the compiler output a sizeable list of errors and warnings.  do you have all the warnings enabled when compiling?

Comment: [`EINVAL` means "Invalid *oflag* or *pmode* argument."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx).  The file mode argument - which you supplied as `384` - is only used if the file flags include `O_CREATE`.  It's possible the C runtime is detecting the mode parameter was supplied by the caller without the `_O_CREAT` flag set.  Also, providing a `mode` parameter as a decimal magic number isn't very clear.  If you're not going to use provided permissions constants such as `S_IREAD`, providing the `mode` parameter in octal is much more understandable.